# Display new geojson data for GeoJSON class on click of button

Tags: reactjs, geojson, react-leaflet

I'm using the React leaflet library. In particular, I'm using the GeoJSON class that comes with the library to render the map that is described by a geojson. Currently my class looks like this:

```
const MyMap = () => {
    const [stateGeoJSON, setStateGeoJSON] = useState(exampleGeoJSON)
    
    const setStateGeoJSON = (newJson) => {
        setStateGeoJSON(newJson)
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <MapContainer
                style={{ height: '90vh'}}
                zoom={zoom}
                maxZoom={12}
                minZoom={5}
                center={mapCenter}
                zoomControl={false}
                maxBounds={mapCenter}
                maxBoundsViscosity={1.0}
            >
                <StateMap geojson={stateGeoJSON}/>
            </MapContainer>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I also have a class called StateMap that is inside of the MyMap class which just looks like this:

```
const StateMap = ({ geojson }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <GeoJSON
                style={districtStyleDefault}
                data={geojson.features}
                onEachFeature={onEachState}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I didn't put the functions "onEachFeature" or the style in this post, but they are there. Basically, my StateMap class takes a prop called "geojson" from MyMap which is the geojson that will be used to render the map in StateMap. This all works.

The problem is I am trying to change the geojson that is being used inside of StateMap on the click of a button. Once the user clicks the button, setStateGeoJSON is called with a new geojson. The state variable called "stateGeoJSON" is then changed. I thought that this would update the GeoJSON component in StateMap but it does not. I have also tried to create state variables within StateMap that change when the prop "geojson" is changed, but this does not change the geojson being used either. I'm not sure how to solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [react-leaflet docs for GeoJSON](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components#geojson), you'll see that the `data` property is *not mutable*, meaning the `GeoJSON` component will not respond to changes in the `data` prop after it has been created.  This is a new feature with react-leaflet v3 which is present all over the place in the library, and is helpful for not causing unnecessary rerenders of react components.

So to change the data, you need to get a ref to the underlying leaflet element, and do it from there, as you would in a vanilla leaflet application.

```js
const StateMap = ({ geojson }) => {

    // get a ref to the underlying L.geoJSON
    const geoJsonRef = useRef()

    // set the data to new data whenever it changes
    useEffect(() => {
      if (geoJsonRef.current){
        geoJsonRef.current. clearLayers()   // remove old data
        geoJsonRef.current.addData(geojson) // might need to be geojson.features
      }
    }, [geoJsonRef, geojson])

    return (
        <div>
            <GeoJSON
                ref={geoJsonRef}
                style={districtStyleDefault}
                data={geojson.features}
                onEachFeature={onEachState}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Upon reading your comment, I looked a little more into react leaflet and found out you can also set a key within the GeoJSON component. Basically, this key has to be unique and once it changes it will rerender the GeoJSON component.

Comment: That's another great method.  Its not specific to react-leaflet, its a built-in react feature, but that's a great way to force react-leaflet to rerender certain components that it wouldn't otherwise.  As long as the new `key` is different from the last, it will rerender.  Great thinking!

Comment: I'm still not sure why the component won't just rerender like a normal component. I'm trying to think of a case where you wouldn't want GeoJSON to rerender when you've given it new data, but can't think of one. I guess it's a good feature since you can just easily add a key on GeoJSON components that you want to rerender automatically though.

Comment: I am using key here and it does the same job, but my problem is I have around 20000 features and a scenario where I have to add remove some of them, lets say 100. In that case it rerenders all 20100 features instead of rendering only the new ones.

Comment: @PremshankarTiwari that sounds like a different / more complex problem than this question is addressing